# Quadcopter holding algorithm

Tags: quadcopter

I am working on a project related to quadcopter. I have also build a algorithm based on PID controller for controlling climb sink rate and also holding but it did not work correctly. My function to correct the motor is throttle += pid_output with the error is computed from taking the error of height and velocity by the function: error = K1*(target altitude - measure altitude) - K2*(velocity). Currently My velocity is calculated by taking the different between current altitude and the past  while altitude is measured from barometric sensor only. Does anyone here have the experience on building a holding algorithm for quadcopter before ? Could you please to have a look at my algorithm or share with me the ideas of altitude control algorithm.

Many thanks,

Comment: In what way does it not work correctly? If it does wild oscillations or is "unstable" in some other sense, perhaps you need to work on tuning your parameters (see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller#Overview_of_methods )

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are implementing PID incorrectly. For starters, you shouldn't be increasing your throttle by pid_output, you should be setting it to it.

```
for each measurement step:
    error = target altitude - measured altitude
    integ = integ + error
    velocity = error - olderror
    olderror = error
    throttle = Kp * error + Ki * integ + Kd * velocity
```

The assumption made here is that the target altitude won't change, if it does, it should be handled properly.
There are more things to consider like prefilter, integral windup handling, etc.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller